# How can we filter fields from nested tables in MikroORM

Tags: node.js, typescript, orm, nestjs, mikro-orm

Im running in to some hardships trying to figure out how to return selected fields from nested joins.

So in my entities i have a "Restaurant" witch have 1:M  relationship with "Product". "Products" have a M:M relationship with "Category. And "Category" have a M:M with "Menu".

Right now im using this snippet to return all the products with the categories and menus populated:

```
const place = await this.placeRepo.findOne(placeID, {
  populate: ['products.categories.menus'],
});
```

And the problem is that it returns all the fields of products, category & menu which is very unnessecary. Only uuid & title is neeccessary basically. So i want to return the data like this:

```
  [
 {
    "uuid": "tCj6soMp6YWcJosTxvjJ1",
    "title": "Burger 2",
    "categories": [
        {
            "uuid": "JUwta7kMG1-DUARA3Tnan",
            "title": "Pizza",
            "menus": [
                {
                    "uuid": "tohzpXtkAN-mW646sphE1",
                    "titleOfMenu": "Lunch",
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
},
```

]

I have tried this snippet for example just to determine the fields of the return for the products but it does not work and i dont know how to get around it:

```
const place = await this.placeRepo.findOne(placeID, {
  populate: ['products.categories.menus'],
  fields: ['products', 'products.title']
});
```

which throws the following error: "TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined"

How is it possible to return selected fields from nested populated entities? Do we have to use a querybuilder instead or am i missing some simple stuff here?

Comment: If you haven't upgraded already, try v5, there were many improvements also in partial loading. If it does not help, prepare a reproduction and file a bug report. Note that you say you want to get rid of the UUID - even with partial loading, PKs are always selected, without that it's not possible to build the entity graph. You might want to mark those properties as hidden instead. https://mikro-orm.io/docs/serializing#hidden-properties

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Sure i will prepare it. Version is: ^5.0.0-dev.540. Actually i think i mentioned i want to always retrieve the uuid & title, so of course uuid should be part of it. Regarding hidden properties, i've went through it as well but there are several other places in the code we need all the fields, it is just this one case where we only need a few. And i believe marking fields as hidden would hide them in every "find" scenario for example, if im not mistaken. The snippet shown above to populate & select fields works actullay on all 1:1 relations on Restaurant but not 1:M.

Comment: If its one place, then just create the custom response yourself. E.g. you could have some method on the entity that would produce such response. You can call `wrap(this).toObject()` to get the serialized/DTO form of the entity, and just iterate on that and remove keys you dont want there. This DTO won't have any circular references so its safe to modify any object in there.

Comment: But you can as well use partial loading for that, I misread that you dont want those PKs there, and its actually the opposite, which sounds like a good use case for partial loading for sure. Are you on v5? If not, better upgrade first, I don't plan to backport things to v4 so even if its a bug, it would be valid only if its still in v5.

Comment: Yeah its in v5. this is the package.json: "@mikro-orm/core": "^5.0.0-dev.540"

Comment: So upgrade to stable 5.0.2, there were at least 200 commits since dev.540 :]

Comment: Oh wow.. It works now. Really smooth smart function there..

Comment: Great! Always good to upgrade to latest versions when you feel like you found a bug :]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Updating to version 5.0.2 and changing the code to this did the work! Actually dont even need to specify the "populate" as mikro orm populates them automatically for you.

```
  const place = await this.placeRepo.findOne(placeID, {
      fields: [
        'products',
        'products.title',
        'products.categories.title',
        'products.categories.menus',
        'products.categories.menus.titleOfMenu',
           ],
      });
```

Comment: Is it possible to unselect certain fields?

Comment: Unfortunately i have not found this function yet in this type of scenario and i dont think it exists. 

I doubt few, if any, ORM even offer that functionality